# Unable to access different subnet

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, router, subnet

[image]

**Router ip:** 192.168.3.1
**Windows server:** 192.168.3.50 (WLan) and 192.168.2.1 (LAN)
**PCs:** 192.168.2.x

I am able to access 192.168.3.50 from laptop (in 3.x network) but unable to access through other interface 192.168.2.1 and its lan pcs 192.168.2.x.

I added a route in my router with Destination LAN NET 192.168.2.0, Subnet Mask 255.255.255.0 and Gateway 192.168.3.50 but still unable to access.

Do I need to add a route in my Windows server as well? If so what will be the route like?

**EDIT**:
- Server and laptop connected to Router through wireless.
- All the PCs are connected to the server through a switch.
- Server is able to access the internet through WLAN interface (192.168.3.50)
- Server and PCs are communicating through LAN interface (192.168.2.x)
- I am able to ping 192.168.3.50 from router but not 192.168.2.1

**Problem**
- 3.x machines (in my case laptop) is not able to access 2.x machines. Not even 192.168.2.1 (which is another ip for server). ping 192.168.3.50 works not 192.168.2.1

As @0wn3r suggested I changed the mask to 255.255.0.0 in router and server but still the same problem.

Comment: Can you check if IP forwarding is enabled ( http://www.itgeared.com/articles/1066-how-to-enable-ip-forwarding-on-windows/ )? And can you reach other 192.168.2.x devices from your windows server?

Comment: ...and check if there are any firewall rules.

Comment: @mulaz IP forwarding is enabled and I can reach 2.x machines from the server

Comment: Problem is 3.x is able to access 2.1 but not 2.101 2.102 etc whereas the server is able to access 2.x

Comment: What is the Firewall / Router OS?

Comment: Make sure win firewall isnt on, it blocks ping. And i would double check the subnet masks on all the devices to be sure theyre 255.255.255.0 and not 255.255.254.0

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, sorry to double post too, but I believe the StackOverflow one may be redirected or deleted (as not appropriate for that site).

Here are my questions again (can't put it in a simple comment):

This is weird: the router should be the one with enough dedicated interface to separate all your lans as needed and route between them.

From the picture it's as if your server (3.50) has 2 interfaces, one in 3.x, the other in 2.x. This should mean that between it and the PCs, there is another device (a switch? hub? another router?) so that they can talk together.

Please update the picture to give all the interfaces you use on each device (router, and server, especially) so we can clearly see what you need to do.

from the picture I can guess:

- the router you show is the Wifi router.
- the laptop and the server both connect to it via WiFi.

But I can't guess:

- how does the server and the PCs connect together? via another switch? via the LAN port of the router? The fact you can't route between them seems to indicate they are not on the same lan at all...

Comment: You are right. The PCs are connected to the server through a switch. I updated the picture but unable to upload it. The problem is 3.x is not detecting 2.x machines but the network is accessible in their own subnets.

Comment: then you have a bit of a problem: for PCs to reach the other 3.x machines, they need to all have a route saying "192.168.3.0/255.255.255.0 is to be sent to 192.168.2.1" and you **also** need to have your 3.50 server able to route, and you also need your other 3.x hosts know that 2.x is behind 3.50 ...complex. I'd recommand: unplug LAN (2.1) from your server at all. Plug the switch to an available LAN interface on the **router** (and give that specific interface the 2.x/24 network, if you use the others for another LAN. OR all to the 2.x network, if possible and available).

Comment: in a nutshell: better to route via the router ^^

Comment: if you want, you could describe what you **need**, ie what needs to be separated on different networks, what could be on the same (for example, lan is much faster than accessing through a router if you want to transfer files between hosts, but in the other hand it lacks separation and can't be filtered/firewalled easily or at all...), what dhcp you need to have, etc... Then list what devices you have (or just precise what the router model is), and we can give an "optimal" setup

Comment: Thanks. Please see the original post in stackoverflow for updated image

Comment: I updated my answer there.

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure your Windows server as a Gateway. You will have 2 ips on Windows server. One on 192.168.3.x and one on 192.168.2.x subnet.

First of find ip on 192.168.2.x subnet using

```
ipconfig/all
```

command in terminal , which would be like 192.168.2.x. You have to provide this ip as a gateway in pcs that are connected in lan.

Comment: Your subnet mask will be 255.255.255.0